# Fetching similar sounding names from a table

Tags: php, mysql

I have a student table namely `stu_table` and student name field is `stu_name`.

In this table there are so many student Like Mrinmoy, Minmoy ,Minmay,Mrinmay,Tanmay,Rajesh,Susanta,Bireshwar  etc.

I would like to fetch those student, whose name sound like Mrinmoy

Comment: That's nice. Good luck with that. Did you have a question?

Comment: More to the point, your question "how do I do that" lacks critical information: what defines "sounds like"? The answer depends on such things as language, minimum required proximity, etc.

Comment: in my "stu_table" i have stored lots of students record . But i want to fetch  all students name whose name sound similar to Mrinmoy.

Comment: You already said that in your question. My comment was about what you define as "similar"? Is "Minmay" "similar"? Is "Minmoy"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`MySQL SOUNDEX`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-string-functions.htm#function_soundex):

```
SELECT * FROM `stu_table` WHERE STRCMP(SOUNDEX(`stu_name`), SOUNDEX('Mrinmoy')) <= 0
```

But I don't think it is very accurate and it's very limited.

[SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2b8c3/1)

Comment: Indeed, `SOUNDEX()` is specifically designed to come up with more false positives than false negatives. For it to be useful, you'll need some sort of UI to allow users to choose from among quite a few alternatives.

Comment: can i pass more than one parameter within SOUNDEX() to get multiple value result. If yes then how to pass it. Please help.

Comment: @user3747398, this belongs in another question.

Answer (score 2):

Double Metaphone is a `SOUNDEX`-like hash algorithm for imprecise matching of Roman-alphabet, English-pronunciation proper-name text. It works tolerably well for other single words besides names.

The Double Metaphone hash algorithm generates either one or two hash values for a word. That's what makes it "double."   For example, there's a village in Massachusetts USA called "Gill". It has the two metaphone hashes with values KL and JL, corresponding to two different pronunciations.

Now, if somebody hears the word "Jill" for that village's name, they'll ask for its metaphone hashes.  They are JL and AL.  To find this match, the double metaphone search must look at four possible matches:

```
Gill     Jill
 KL       JL    mismatch
 KL       AL    mismatch
 JL       JL    match!
 JL       AL    mismatch
```

Therefore, "Gill" and "Jill" are considered matching by double metaphone.

Many words only have one metaphone hash. Those are easier to match.

A MySQL stored function to generate the metaphone hashes can be found here.

http://www.atomodo.com/code/double-metaphone/

But beware: given a word with two metaphone hashes it returns them in one string separated by a semicolon.

Like the ancient and honorable SOUNDEX, Double Metaphone favors false positive matches rather than false negative. But it has better rates on both, mostly due to its double-hash capability.

Answer (score 0):

Mysql has operator **SOUNDS LIKE**

Try look at it

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#operator_sounds-like

Comment: The quoted link states: "This function, as currently implemented, is intended to work well with strings that are in the English language only. Strings in other languages may not produce reliable results." "Mrinmoy" isn't an english word.